# Picocli: how to share options between parent command and subcommands

Tags: shell, command-line, command, picocli

How to support shared options across all (or some) commands and subcommands? For example, if an end user provides `--stacktrace` anywhere in the command line arguments, any errors printed will include the stacktrace.

We can use a Mixin to define a boolean `--stacktrace` option, and include this Mixin in all (sub)commands, or use inheritance and let all commands subclass a class that defines a boolean `--stacktrace` option, but either way, that would define a separate boolean option for each command. Which option is true depends on where in the args the user put `--stacktrace`, so figuring out if `--stacktrace` was provided would mean iterating over all parent commands and seeing if any are true.

It would be nice to have a more convenient way to detect whether the user specified such a shared option.

*(See also https://github.com/remkop/picocli/issues/580)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update: with picocli 4.3 there are two ways to accomplish this:

- [inherited options](https://picocli.info/#_inherited_options)
- let subcommands use a mixin that [delegates to the parent](https://picocli.info/#_use_case_configure_log_level_with_a_global_option) command (so the state modified by the option is in one place)

---

One way to accomplish this is to make the boolean field static:

```
class Shared {
    @Option(names = "--stacktrace")
    static boolean stacktrace;
}
```

You would still need to either subclass or use a mixin to define this option in each command and subcommands:

```
@Command(subcommands = {Subcommand1.class, Subcommand2.class /*, ...*/}
class MyCommand {
    @Mixin
    Shared shared = new Shared();

    // ...
}

@Command(name = "subcommand1")
class Subcommand1 {
    @Mixin
    Shared shared = new Shared();

    // ...
}
```

The nice thing about this design is that there is now a single place where the application can detect whether the end user specified `--stacktrace`: the static boolean field:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    assert Shared.stacktrace == false;

    MyCommand myCommand = new MyCommand();
    CommandLine.parseArgs(myCommand, "subcommand1", "--stacktrace");

    assert Shared.stacktrace == true;
}
```

Comment: 2 pitfalls I stepped into when using this: Adding `@Option` to a static field did not work for me, I needed a non-static setter method. Furthermore, when using inheritance as you described, I could not use `@Mixin static Foo foo` with `class Foo { @Option Bar bar }` inside the _superclass_, I needed `class Foo { @Option static Bar bar }` instead to get the desired behaviour.

Comment: To be clear with the second pitfall: `class Shared { @Mixin static Foo foo }` with `class Foo { @Option Bar bar }` and `@Command class MyCommand extends Shared {}` did not work.

Comment: I updated my answer for [picocli 4.3](https://github.com/remkop/picocli/releases/tag/v4.3.0).

Comment: This looks great, especially the inherited options! From the docs, the MIXEE looks a bit confusing, but it might be fine once i got my hands dirty and tried it ;)